# Google Developer Console OAuth Client Secret contains no "secret"?

Tags: php, android, oauth

I'm trying to set up google play services sign in. I have an android client and a php backend. The PHP backend requires the client server.

When I download the client secret json from the google developer console, I get a json that looks like this :

`{"installed":{"client_id":"XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"api-project-XXXXXX","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}}`

Where is the "secret" here? the link between the client_id and the project_id? Is this what a normal client secret json is supposed to look like? Currently the code is following the android PHP samples and not working, and I'm suspecting that the secret isnt set up correctly.

Am I looking in the right place?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On [Credential page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) of your project click `Create credentials`  →  `OAuth client ID` → `Web application` → `Create` and then you should see the screen like this one below. Or you can just click on an existing `Client ID` to see the Client secret. Check out also [this link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app#creatingcred) for more information.

[image: Client secret]

Comment: Thanks. After reading a bit, I created a "Web application" that gives me this info. Now I have a different problem - when I try to authenticate I get the following error :
"{ "error" : "invalid_grant", "error_description" : "Incorrect token type." }"

Any idea what that might be?